# Django rest framework- blog post comment delete permission for admin user and owner user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**does anyone know how to set delete permisssion for commented owner to delete the comment and for the admin user, delete all comments**

**Serializers.py**

```
class DeleteCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CommentModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Views.py**

```
class CommentDeleteView(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser,IsOwner]
    queryset = CommentModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeleteCommentSerializer
    
    def perform_delete(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

**Permissions.py**

```
class IsOwner(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in ['PUT','DELETE']:
            return True
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope so it will work

```
  class IsOwner(BasePermission):
     def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_superuser or request.user.admin:
           return True
        else:
           return False
```

Comment: [Tanveer Ahamad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12094976/tanveer-ahmad) thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can set this type of permission like so:

add field in your User Table

```
is_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

when this field against the user is True it's mean the user is owner. or you can on the base of set is_superuser or admin field.

```
 class IsOwner(BasePermission):
     def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_owner or request.user.admin:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: [Shahab Khalid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7172452/shahab-khalid) thanks for the solution it worked fine for me